# Communication through Messaging in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios5, messaging

I'm Developing an application. It is the Communication Between iPhone Application and a Hardware Device. in that Hardware Device We are Having SIM Card and also that Hardware Device had Some Settings. Now my task is i have to Modify that Settings By using our Mobile Application through Messaging.

I am able to send that settings in Some Message format to that Hardware Device.after settings have been changed the Hardware Device sends a response message. Now my Problem is I am Unable to Read that Message From My Application.

I Google it in Some Sources they Said:

1.There is No possibility of Reading SMS By using our Application.

2.It is Possible Only if the Phone is Jail Breaked.

is there any alternative solution for this i.e Communication Between iPhone Application and a Hardware Device through only messaging.

Comment: Don't forget to upvote / mark top answer questions that have helped you. If no answer has helped you, leave a comment and add further details. Others facing the same issue will want to know what solved your problem

Answer (score 0):

Why the hell are you using SMS for this? why not run a server socket on the device that listens for connection, implement some way of connecting remotely (intermediate server, static ip, UPNP etc) and connect and send data via TCP.

As you have stated in you question iOS doesn't allow you access to SMS, you will not be able to achieve this, unless the iPhone is jailbroken, there might be some level of access then but I have no experience with jailbreaking.

Comment: Thanks for u r answer.It's the requirement Operate that device by using only messaging.

Comment: @Suresh unless jailbraking is an option for you, and I'm not sure you can do this then either, there is no way this is going to be possible using SMS. You simply cant get at the messages. If the device has a sim card it can have a data connection, if it has a data connection it can use networking protocols to communicate. Thats the only way this will work